# Implementing AMD in JavaScript using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd, revealing-module-pattern

I am totally new to RequireJS so I'm still trying to find my way around it. I had a project that was working perfectly fine, then I decided to use RequireJS so I messed it up :)

With that out of the way, I have a few questions about RequireJS and how it figures out everything. I have the file hierarchy inside the scripts folder:

[image]

I have the following line inside my `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
<script data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/require-2.0.6.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here's my bootstrap.js file:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'jQuery': {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },
        'Knockout': {
            exports: 'ko'
        },
        'Sammy': {
            exports: 'Sammy'
        },
        'MD': {
            exports: 'MD'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'jQuery': 'jquery-1.8.1.min.js',
        'Knockout': 'knockout-2.1.0.js',
        'Sammy': 'sammy/sammy.js',
        'MD': 'metro/md.core.js',
        'pubsub': 'utils/jquery.pubsub.js',
        'waitHandle': 'utils/bsynchro.jquery.utils.js',
        'viewModelBase': 'app/metro.core.js',
        'bindingHandlers': 'app/bindingHandlers.js',
        'groupingViewModel': 'app/grouping-page.js',
        'pagingViewModel': 'app/paging-page.js'
    }
});

require(['viewModelBase', 'bindingHandlers', 'Knockout', 'jQuery', 'waitHandle', 'MD'], function (ViewModelBase, BindingHandlers, ko, $, waitHandle, MD) {
    BindingHandlers.init();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        waitHandle.waitForFinalEvent(function () {
            MD.UI.recalculateAll();
        }, 500, "WINDOW_RESIZING");
    });

    var viewModelBase = Object.create(ViewModelBase);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelBase);
    viewModelBase.initialize();
});

    require(['viewModelBase', 'bindingHandlers', 'Knockout'], function (ViewModelBase, BindingHandlers, ko) {
        BindingHandlers.init();

        var viewModelBase = new ViewModelBase();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModelBase);
        viewModelBase.initialize();
    });
```

Then I implemented my modules by using the `define` function. An example is the pubsub module:

```
define(['jQuery'], function ($) {
    var 
        publish = function(eventName) {
            //implementation
        },
        subscribe = function(eventName, fn) {
            //implementation
        }
    return {
        publish: publish,
        subscribe: subscribe
    }
});
```

I've basically done the same thing to all of my javascript files. Note that the actual file containing the pubsub module is `jquery.pubsub.js` inside the `/Scripts/utils` folder. This is also the case with other modules as well.

**UPDATE:**

Ok I updated my bootstrap file now that I *think* I understand what a shim is and why I should be using it. But it's still not working for me, although I've also declared all the paths that I think would've caused me trouble in getting them right. The thing is that it's not even going into my `require` callback inside the bootstrap file, so I guess I still have a problem in the way I'm configuring or defining my modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one, if you are going to use a non-amd library, say jQuery, with require and have the jQuery function passed to the callback, you need to specify a shim with exports in your require config, like so:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        jQuery: {
            exports: '$'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jQuery: 'jquery-1.8.1.min.js',
    }
});
```

Other than that I'm not sure I understand what your issue is exactly.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for your answer. My issue is that RequireJS is not resolving the dependencies properly. For instance, the first error that appears in the console is "jQuery is not defined" in the pubsub module.

Comment: Where is the `_Layout.cshtml` file in your directory structure?

Comment: Ok I've read more about what a shim is and how to configure them and all that but I still couldn't get it to work. I've updated my post. What am I still doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Check your network panel and see if there are any 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC take a look at [RequireJS for .NET](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2012/09/intro-requirejs-for-asp-net-mvc/)

The RequireJS for .NET project smoothly integrates the RequireJS framework with ASP.NET MVC on the server side using xml configuration files, action filter attributes, a base controller for inheritance and helper classes.

Comment: Seems interesting! But I'd rather understand how this thing works first before I start using other people's libraries, but thanks anyway :) By the way, I've updated my post above, could you take a look please?

Answer (score 0):

I did not completely understand what the problem is. But if it relates to JS libraries to be loaded with require.js then this boot file works for me:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "/scripts/jquery-1.8.2",
        "sammy": "/scripts/sammy-0.7.1"
    },
    shim: {
        "sammy": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "Sammy"
        }
    }
});

require(["jquery", "sammy"], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("DOM ready");
    });
});
```

Please, note, there is no '.js' in paths.

BTW, if you use MVC 4, you don't need @Url.Content in 'href' and 'src' any more.